# Flash[:error] based on validates_uniqueness_of :login, :email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a user model that `validates_uniqueness_of :login, :e-mail`. When a user enters his information into user/new.html.erb, the create action may fail because of either of the two fields.

How can I customize my flash to be more helpful to the user, telling them which (or both) of the fields they need to change the next time around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
flash[:error] = @user.errors.full_messages.to_sentence
```

should do the job. But I would recommend that you display the error right next to the field which contains invalid data. Plugins like formtastic will do this for you automatically.

[Check the API](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Errors/full_messages) for more ideas.

Comment: This is giving me: `["Email has already been taken", "Email has already been taken", "Login has already been taken", "Login has already been taken"]`. How can I make it more readable?

Comment: Have you applied ActiveSupport's `to_sentence` to it (I added it during an edit)? It should convert that array into `"Email has already been taken, and Login has already been taken."`.

Comment: Also, unless you perform a redirect, you might consider using flash.now[:error] to prevent it from being displayed on the next page again (flash is saved for next request, flash.now is not).